# How do I put a Pace / 2-Wire 3801HGV into bridge/passthrough mode

Tags: networking

Any ideas / links / etc that explain how to get a Pace / 2-Wire 3801HGV into bridge mode? I want the 3801 to function as a modem only and my Unifi Security Gateway (USG-PRO-4) to handle everything else.

Based on a few posts I found, I enabled notification of the "Router-Behind-Router Detection" event under System Info > Event Notifications in the 3801 portal. Unfortunately, now every device on the network needs to enter the 3801 password to get to the internet. This is no good on many levels and I have a sense there's more to putting this device into bridge mode.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to get a Pace / 2-Wire 3801HGV into bridge mode?

It is not possible to put your modem completely in bridge mode.

However the following instructions will set it up so that most router functions will work correctly.

It may not completely solve your problem - but only you will we able to tell us that.

> There is no true bridge mode on the 2Wire routers.  However, you can
> still configure it such that almost all functions of your own router
> will work properly.
>
> 1. Set your router's WAN interface to get an IP address via DHCP.  This is required at first so that the 2Wire recognizes your router.
> 2. Plug your router's WAN interface to one of the 2Wire's LAN interfaces.
> 3. Restart your router, let it get an IP address via DHCP.
> 4. Log into the 2Wire router's interface.  Go to Settings -> Firewall -> Applications, Pinholes, and DMZ
> 5. Select your router under section (1).
> 6. Click the DMZPlus button under section (2).
> 7. Click the Save button.
> 8. Restart your router, when it gets an address via DHCP again, it will be the public outside IP address.  At this point, you can leave
>    your router in DHCP mode (make sure the firewall on your router allows
>    the DHCP renewal packets, which will occur every 10 minutes), or you
>    can change your router's IP address assignment on the WAN interface to
>    static, and use the same settings it received via DHCP.
> 9. On the 2Wire router, go to Settings -> Firewall -> Advanced Configuration
> 10. Uncheck the following: Stealth Mode, Block Ping, Strict UDP Session Control.
> 11. Check everything under Outbound Protocol Control except NetBIOS.
> 12. Uncheck NetBIOS under Inbound Protocol Control.
> 13. Uncheck all the Attack Detection checkboxes (7 of them).
> 14. Click Save.
>
> Your router should now be able to route as if the 2Wire was a straight
> bridge, for the most part.

Source: [U-verse for BUSINESS? : 2Wire 3600HGV bridge mode? or another AT&T supported VDSL modem? | AT&T Community Forums](https://forums.att.com/conversations/att-internet-equipment/uverse-for-business-2wire-3600hgv-bridge-mode-or-another-att-supported-vdsl-modem/5defbfacbad5f2f606a66358?commentId=5deffb02bad5f2f606cf5807#M3631)